# Create list to be added in Gtk.ListBoxRow

Tags: c, gtk, glib, vala, elementary-os

I created a List using this code.

[image]

Now when I try to access the elements of the list, the compiler displays this error:
[image]

Can someone suggest how to solve this problem?

This is how I try to access each element in the list and add it to the ListBoxRow:
[image]

Comment: Maybe try [Gee.List](https://valadoc.org/gee-0.8/Gee.List.html)?

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: I declared the list using var cities = new GLib.List<string> ();, and that worked, but now the compiler displays an error saying cannot convert unowned string to unowned Gtk.Widget for the line row.add (source)

Comment: That's because you can't add a string to a widget, you have to add another widget (probably a Gtk.Label?)

Comment: Yeah, I undetstood that. I have solved the problem now. But my main question is still unanswered.

Comment: Can you show how you declared the `cities` variable?

Comment: Also, please try to use code blocks instead of screenshots. It makes the code searchable (and better fit for reading in certain cases).

Comment: I deleted the code in the above screenshots and used a completely different method.
So should I delete the question ?